# The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

Tags: c#

In ASP.NET MVC 4.8.1 Framework, after typing **@Html.LabelFor()**, **@Html.EditorFor()**, **@Html.ValidationMessageFor()** in a view, I'm getting this error:

**The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.**

I have added assembly reference System.Core.dll, Version 4.0.0.0, Runtime Version v4.0.30319, and also I did in web.config, but nothing! How can the problem be solved?